# How to verify authenticity of Unity game client from server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, unity-game-engine, iis, certificate

I have an ASP.Net Core server with both http and https enabled. It runs with IIS 10, ASP.NET CORE ~6.0.

I have followed the following documentation: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth](Microsoft's ASP.NET Authentication Docs)

Based on that I made a class for handling authentication of incoming client requests

```
public class CertValidationService
{
    public bool ValidateCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
    {
        Log("\nInside validate"); //NOT triggered
        /*my custom verification logic*/
        return true;
    }

    public static void Handler(CertificateAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        Log("\nCalled handler"); //NOT triggered
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnAuthenticationFailed = OnFailed,
            OnCertificateValidated = OnSuccess,
            OnChallenge = OnChallenged
        };
    }

    private static Task OnChallenged(CertificateChallengeContext context){
        Log("\nInside challenge");
        return Task.CompletedTask; //triggered
    }
    private static Task OnFailed(CertificateAuthenticationFailedContext context){
        context.Fail("Failed!");
        return Task.CompletedTask; //NOT triggered
    }
    private static Task OnSuccess(CertificateValidatedContext context){
        Log("\nInside OnSuccess"); //NOT triggered
        var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<CertValidationService>();
        if (validationService != null && validationService.ValidateCertificate(context.ClientCertificate)){
            Log("\nValidated!");
            var claims = new List<Claim>{
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ClientCertificate.SubjectName.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
            };
            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                new ClaimsIdentity(
                    claims,
                    context.Scheme.Name //CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
                )
            );
            context.Success();
        } else {
            Log("\nBad Certificate");
            context.Fail("Bad Certificate");
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    public static void Log(string log) {
        string path = "logs.txt";
        try {
            File.AppendAllText(path, log);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added certificate validation using the above class, as follows, and while the route triggered for non-authenticated endpoints, the ValidateCertificate method and the success and failure events are not fired for the "weather" route given here. It is required that the server recognizes that incoming requests are from a counterfeit apk or not.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

// ADDED VALIDATION
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CertValidationService>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(CertValidationService.Handler);
// ----------------

builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => { options.AllowSynchronousIO = true; });
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And I have setup some routes that require authorization as follows:

```
// baseURL/myroute/weather
[ApiController]
[Route("myroute")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "weather")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public string<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return "data";
    }
    [HttpGet(Name = "weather_noauth")]
    public string<WeatherForecast2> Get()
    {
        return "data";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could because the cerificate is not recognized valid in your machine. You may need to add this:

```
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
    {
        options.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
        options.AllowAnyClientCertificate();//important
    });
});
```

Comment: I am confused.. Its for IIS not Kestrel

Comment: I searched around but cannot find anything close to that option on IIS. I have set the settings on IIS for accepting (not mandatorily requiring) client certificates.